# Steps for internationalisation in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, localization

I've been trying to add a Portuguese translation to my app.  At the moment it's all in English.  (well, it started that way).

I'm using a Storyboard for the main part of the UI.  There are also a couple of additional xib files for reusable UI in table etc...

Anyway, I set out on the path of trying to internationalise the app and managed to convert the Storyboard to Portuguese.

I then tried to set up some strings (just a couple to begin with) to make translations of those also.

I've now got an storyboard that's only in Portuguese (I lost the English version) and none of the strings are being translated properly anyway.

I've set all the string back to just use @"blah" now (I'd put NSLocalizedString in a couple of places).

So I should be back to square one (once I fix the storyboard).

Anyway, is there a list of steps somewhere of how to go about making an app localised?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of tutorials available - this is one of the good ones: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial

This will definitely help you to get started real quick!

However, if you are on iOS6 xCode 4.5 you should also check the new features regarding localization. Apple now has also gon the route to have just one XIB (not like before multiple XIBs, one per language - which was impossible to maintain)

Probably the most important point is to always use `NSLocalizedString`, so there is no need for multiple XIBs. And then it's real easy to just add a new strings file for each language.

All you have to do then is in the Project Editor select your project -> select the Info tab on the right -> scroll all the way down -> there you find the localizations, press the little + on the buttom to add a new language. That's it.

Comment: Thanks.  That has worked now.  Having major problems using genstrings though :( It just doesn't output anything. Either that or I get... "find: main.m: unknown primary or operator" when using... "find ./ -name *.m -print0 | xargs -0 genstrings -o en.lproj"

Comment: I know - I was really disappointed to see what kind of rudimentary kind of command line tools one has to use. However, you need to do this only at the very end of the developmentprocess - only once. Then just add single new elements to the strings file directly - this will be the easy part :-)

Comment: Nice, thanks. I eventually got it working but soon realised it's best to do once as I kept overwriting my file each time I did it :D Thanks again for the help.